# Library or Best Practice for Buffering Data Streams (via HTTP)

Tags: java, spring, buffering, output-buffering

### Preface

I have two applications:

- Frontend Application **FA**
- Event Bus Application **EPA**

Both communicate through HTTP/Server Sent Events. The FA subscribes with JavaScript to the EPA. The EPA publishes to the FA if an event occurs. The JavaScript then handles this event using a callback and appends a given HTML textbox' content with the new event (line of text).

### The issue

When the EPA now starts to spam events - in my case around 1700 entries - then the FA stalls because of the high amount of async handling of those callbacks.

### The question

I already wrote a buffering service for another application but that really was a pain in the a** where I had to consider a lot of corner cases. This left me with a huge effort.

What I'm looking for is a way to buffer these events. Like I'd like to have 30 events being collected before the actual publish will happen.

Is there any kind of library or feature integrated into the spring framework (which I use)

Comment: I guess I'll ask the obvious question: why is the event bus spamming the front-end? Do you have any control over that?

Comment: these events are actual log messages of another application. In this application is a iteration over a list and for every item a log statement

Comment: Wouldn't a poll mechanism be preferred in this case?

Comment: @Synch I'm not a friend of polling since the chance is there, that an empty poll might occur which infers useless resources wasting. SSE plus buffering is the solution that fits right in my opinion

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in the frontend or the backend? 1700 shouldn't be much, where's the hotspot?

Comment: @Kayaman good point here. Since Server Sent Events are handled one by one by EventSource JS API I have to way to buffer it in the frontend - and the callbacks are the bottleneck. So I need to group up log messages to bundles in the backend and deliver a big string to reduce the overhead for every single log line